# How to route to different controller base of route value type in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I'm trying to keep my url a little cleaner by using the same pattern for my urls. here are my routes:

```
app.route('/inbox')
    .get(user.inbox);


app.route('/:messageId')
    .get(user.message);
```

Is there a way to keep this pattern and make the code to distinguish the value and point to different controllers?

Comment: Distinguish which value? The message id?

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work as it is. use req.params.messageId it get the message id in the user.message function